# How to shorten REST JSON with foreign keys

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have a `User` object, and `Role` object. Each user has one role. In database, the role is foreign key to table `roles`, where each role has just numerical id as primary key, and some textual name of the role ("admin", "user").

Now, I want to be able to simply `POST` the following JSON:

```json
{"name": "John", "role": "admin"}
```

How to do that?

I end up wit this error:

```
Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Role] from String value ('admin'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7b8a088a; line: 1, column: 17] (through reference chain: User[\"role\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, Role] from String value ('admin'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7b8a088a; line: 1, column: 17] (through reference chain: User[\"role\"])
```

User model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Role model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides correcting your json, I think You'll need at least two things : a String constructor for `Role`, and the `@Column` annotation with `unique=true` on `Role.name`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
  private String name;

  public Role() {}

  public Role(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  // Getters and setters...
}
```

Then you'll have to make sure that when you save a `User` the correct `Role` is loaded from database and substituted in `User.role`, otherwise you may get a `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` (because you're trying to save a new `Role` instance with a name that is already taken).

Comment: From what package should I import @Unique?

Comment: sorry, I didn't check it. You should use `@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)` (`javax.persistence.Column`). See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid, change it to this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "role": "admin"
}
```